# How to understand net visibility and raw visibility?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, terminology

To qualify the purity and degree of entanglement, we can perform a Bell test (Franson type). In this case, we focus on net visibility. However, it seems like raw visibility is more important in quantum teleportation. so what is the difference bewteen net visibility and raw visibility? Why focus on different types of visibility in these two situations?